# Map different values in range intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Time_0': [5, 5, 5],
                        'Time_1': [8, 10, 12],
                        'Values': [10.0, 15.0, 20.0]})
```

I need to distribute the `Values` into a new cash flow dataframe, in every row within the `time_0` and `time_1` intervals. I currently have it mapped into one row:

```
df_CF = pd.DataFrame({'Values': [0.0 for n in (range(0, 16))],
                      'Months': range(0, 16)})
df_CF['Values'] = df_CF['Months'].map(df_data.set_index('Time_1')['Values']).fillna(value=0)
```

However, I'm not quite sure how I can extend it to the whole range. The output should be:

```
**Time   Values**
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
5        45
6        45
7        45
8        45
9        35
10       35
11       20
12       20
13       0
14       0
15       0
16       0
```

Comment: Why does your input have all the ranges starting with 5 instead of 5/8/10 like your output ranges start?

Comment: how do you get 45 for range 5-8? what is that sum?

Comment: Since the values 10, 15 and 20 all start at time 5, range 5-8 is comprised of the sum of all of them, until value 10's end at time 8, which then is only comprised of values 15 and 20. Hope it is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your edit:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Time_0':[5,5,5]
               ,'Time_1':[8,10,12]
               ,'Values':[10.0,15.0,20.0]})

df_dict={"Range": [k for k in range(20)],
    "CF": [0 for k in range(20)]}

for j in range(len(df_dict["Range"])):
    for z in range(len(df_data)):
        if df_data['Time_0'].iloc[z]<=df_dict['Range'][j] and df_data['Time_1'].iloc[z]>=df_dict['Range'][j]:
            df_dict['CF'][j]=df_dict['CF'][j]+df_data['Values'].iloc[z]
```

Output:

```
    CF
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   0.0
5   45.0
6   45.0
7   45.0
8   45.0
9   35.0
10  35.0
11  20.0
12  20.0
13  0.0
14  0.0
15  0.0
16  0.0
17  0.0
18  0.0
19  0.0
```

I am sure more elegant solutions do exist though.

Comment: Hi Dav2357, the reasoning behind your answer is correct, but sorry I didn't make myself clear on how the output should be. I have updated it

Comment: @JordiYu No problem, I'll edit my answer. However I am unsure about the output you posted, shouldn't it be 45 for 5-8, 35 for 8-10 and 20 for 10-12? Why it goes all the way up to 15?

Comment: True, my bad again, was thinking about another numerical example. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much Dav2357!!
The only issue is that after implementing it, a "value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a df" error pops-up, so I guess I'll have to work on a copy of it